# image behind td (similar to background)

Tags: css

I have a table that holds a menu, each menu item is central-aligned in a new row.

```
<table><tr>
<td> Menu item 1 </td>
<td> Menu item 2 </td>
...
</tr></table>
```

I want to put some images "behind" that menu, so lets say I put an image in the first row, and make it transparent, so it spans thru the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you wouldn't just use a background - that's exactly what you're describing here. To add a background image, you could use

```
<table style="background: url(path/to/image);">
...
```

Except that inline styles are usually discouraged, so you could also use this css:

```
table {
    background: url(path/to/image);
}
```

And, while this doesn't seem like it'll be an issue for you, you want to have a faster load time, you could use css classes instead.

```
.menu {
    background: url(path/to/image);
}
```

and change your `<table>` to `<table class="menu">`.